# Odoo12 custom module

Tags: module, odoo, customization

Am trying to run a custom module on an odoo12 instance and getting this error code below.

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 653, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 312, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 695, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 344, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 337, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 938, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 517, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "D:\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 749, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "D:\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 71, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 442, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "D:\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 535, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 426, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 318, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 181, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\module.py", line 368, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "D:\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\module.py", line 82, in load_module
    exec(open(modfile, 'rb').read(), new_mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

After updating the apps in debug mode am unable to install if hence getting the above error. ill appreciate your help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure on your `__init__.py`

```
import models
```

change to

```
from . import models
```

Thanks